# Google account for business android phones

Tags: google, android

We are going to supply our engineers with Note3 phones (due to the fact these are some of the only devices that come with real stylus') so that they can take signatures on jobs etc. I'm grappling with the concept of having to setup individual Google accounts for each user. This is something I want to avoid. I've considered setting up one specific Google account to use on all phones but this seems like a security risk and a pain to manage (lesser so than individual accounts). I may want to install certain apps from the app store, and I would like to use the phone tracking and remote disable features. Is it worth setting up a Google apps account for this purpose? We already have Exchange happily working for the users and I don't really want to scrap our infrastructure just to switch over to Google. Running these phones without a google account somehow feels wrong, and I feel that I'm missing out. What other solutions have  people set up to get round these problems, or did that find no problems without a google account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is "Mobile Device Management".

Comment: Yep, sounds about right :)